# How to create tasks in Microsoft Dynamics CRM using quick campaign

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I have a specific case in which I need to create tasks for a group of selected/filtered accounts.

Firstly I  thought that I could use quick campaigns. But quick campaigns allows users to create phone calls, appointments, letters, emails,... but not tasks. 
I thought I can work around this, by creating workflow, that would deactivate a phone call created by quick campaign and create new task with the same subject and due date as previous phone call... Sadly there is an issue with this approach. Task created this way won't have regarding field (as task cannot be associated with quick campaigns) and I cannot fill it from call to field using workflow.

Other options I thought of:
- Creating on demand workflow to create tasks for selected accounts. Downside is that this can be run only on selected records (max 250 in page). 
- Creating on demand workflow to create tasks + java script button to run this workflow for all filtered accounts in view. Downside: not sure if this is possible + I want to avoid code writing.
- Creating custom workflow to parse call-to field from phone calls created by quick campaign to fill in task regarding field. But this requires programming, which I would prefer to avoid.

Please share your insights and possible approaches to this issue.